# Hooking into IIS and find .NET DLLs

Tags: .net, iis

I'm working on a small project to trace the functionality of ASP.NET applications.

I use native code to attach to the IIS worker process (w3wp.exe) but I can not see the loaded application dlls. I can confirm that they are indeed loaded by the process using ProcMon, but I still only have visibility into the native dlls loaded by the process.

How would i go about enumerate the .NET DLLs loaded? I feel like I have to access the .NET runtime to enumerate the loaded DLLs but I can not find much documentation on it.

I appreciate any insight into the process.

Comment: What kind of code did you use? Something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process

Comment: I used 

```var modules = Process.GetCurrentProcessById("process id")
                .Modules
                .Cast<ProcessModule>()
                .Select(m=>new {Name = m.ModuleName, Size = m.ModuleMemorySize })
                .ToArray();```

Comment: "I use native code"? What you used is not native.

Comment: Are you saying native code would give the results I’m looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you could use [Process.Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.modules?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Modules) Property to acheive your requirement.

The Process.Modules property which you can enumerate all Modules (exe and .dll's) loaded by the process.

```
 //get the process firstly  
foreach (var module in IISprocess.Modules)
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Module: {0}", module.FileName));
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach and I still wasn't able to see the .NET managed assemblies loaded by the application.